# OCaml: How to remove all non-alphabetic characters from a string?

Tags: regex, unicode, ocaml

How do I remove all the non-alphabetic characters from a string?

E.g.

```
"Wë_1ird?!"  ->  "Wëird"
```

In Perl, I'd do this with `=~ s/[\W\d_]+//g`.  In Python, I'd use

```
re.sub(ur'[\W\d_]+', u'', u"Wë_1ird?!", flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Etc.

AFAICT, `Str.regex` does not support `\W`, `\d`, etc.  (I can't
tell whether it supports Unicode, but somehow I doubt it).

Comment: Does not support `\d` or `\w` , really ? Nothing left but  character classes and quantifiers.

Comment: @sln: If it does, please show me where; here's the documentation I've been working with: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html

Comment: Have you tried `[^a-zA-Z]+` ?

Comment: @sln: if you look at the example I provided, you will immediately see that `[^a-zA-Z]+` won't work, because it will correctly eliminate `ë`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in regexes and utf, but if I were in your shoes, then I would use `re2` library, and this is my first approximation:

```
open Core.Std
open Re2.Std
open Re2.Infix

let drop _match = ""

let keep_alpha s = Re2.replace ~/"\\PL" ~f:drop s
```

The first three lines open libraries and bring their definitions into scope. You do not need to open library to use it, but otherwise you need to prefix each defintion. OCaml core library is specially designed in a such way, that a user should open `Std` submodule to bring all necessary defintions to scope. `Re2` library is from the same guys and have a consisten conventions. `open Re2.Infix` will bring infix (and prefix operators) to scope, namely `~/` that will create a regex from a string. The `drop` function just ignores its argument and returns an empty string. I've prefixed parameter with an underscore, since it is a convention for unused parameteers (respected by a compiler). You can also use just a plain uderscore, as a wild card instead, like `let drop _ = ""`. Next is `keep_alpha` function that will substitute any utf symbol that doesn't match a utf letter class with an empty string, i.e., remove it from the output.

#### Update

I've checked my code, and fixed errors. Also, I would like to show, how to play with this code in toplevel. You've several options, but the easiest is to use `coretop` script that ships with `core` library. It uses `utop` toplevel, so make sure that you have installed it:

```
 $ opam install -y utop
```

Once, it is done, you can start toplevel:

```
 $ coretop -require re2
```

this `-require re2` flag will automatically find and load `re2` library to your toplevel. You can load additional libraries without restarting `utop` with the following command:

```
 # #require "libname";;
```

The first `#` is a toplevel's prompt, you shouldn't type it, but the second is a start of directive, so make sure that actually type it. Any directive should be started from `#` symbol. There're other useful directives in utop, namely:

```
 # #use "filename.ml";;   (* will load and evaluate filename.ml      *)
 # #list;;                (* will list all available packages        *)
 # #typeof "keep_alpha";; (* will infer and print type of expression *)
```

Toplevel will not evaluate your code until you terminate it with `;;` sequence. You may sometimes see this ugly `;;` in a real code, but it is not needed, it is just to say the toplevel, that you want it to evaluate your code right at this place, and show you the result.

Answer (score 6):

`Str` doesn't support Unicode. Assuming you are dealing with UTF-8 encoded data. You can use [Uutf](http://erratique.ch/software/uutf) and [Uucp](http://erratique.ch/software/uucp) as follows:

```ml
let keep_alpha s =
  let b = Buffer.create 255 in
  let add_alpha () _ = function
  | `Malformed _ -> Uutf.Buffer.add_utf_8 b Uutf.u_rep
  | `Uchar u -> if Uucp.Alpha.is_alphabetic u then Uutf.Buffer.add_utf_8 b u
  in
  Uutf.String.fold_utf_8 add_alpha () s;
  Buffer.contents b

# keep_alpha "Wë_1ird?!";;
- : string = "Wëird"
```

Comment: Let me thank you explicitly for posting this.  I did not accept it simply because it's more advanced than I can handle (in contrast to ivg's answer).  But going over the pages for your modules `Uutf` and `Uucp` blew me away.  The word "dazzling" comes to mind.  They are shining models of software development and open source standards, and by themselves gave new impetus to my desire to learn OCaml (which I'd started to have second thoughts about, due to an exceptionally difficult start).  Your code is now for me something to aim for.  In short, bravo, bravo, bravo...

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the kind words and perseverate in your OCaml endeavours.