# How to omit "open ..."?

Tags: ocaml

Suppose I have some file `frobozz.ml` whose first line is:

```
open Foo
```

I understand that if I get rid of this line<sup>1</sup>, `frobozz.ml` may no longer compile, unless I also replace some identifiers `X` in the rest of its content with their "fully qualified" form `Foo.X`.

Is there an efficient/safe way (as opposed to compile-and-see, i.e. trial-and-error) to determine which identifiers `X` in `frobozz.ml` I would need to do this to (if I delete its `open Foo` line)?

(Sorry for the stupid question: I'm very new with OCaml.)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>
Why do I want to do get rid of the `open ...` lines?  Three reasons: 1) at the moment, adding a line of the form `open Foo` results in a compiler error at a line that used to compile fine before making that addition; I'm hoping that by avoiding the `open Foo` line altogether I will be able to compile the file; 2) at this stage in my learning of OCaml, that is, until I become more familiar with the contents of the various packages/modules I think it would be more instructive to work with the full qualified names, and thus keep the provenance of everything completely clear, even if it means typing inconveniently long identifiers; 3) *in principle*, I think namespaces are *great*; I don't like to work with unqualified identifiers whenever there is the risk of inadvertent shadowing (of a previously defined identifier by a latter definition), since "shadowing bugs" can be *really difficult to catch*; if I want to reduce typing (or simply make my code look less cluttered), and if my language supports it, I prefer to alias the namespace to some short string; e.g. in Python, of the following three possibilities supported by the language, I prefer the last one:</sub>

```
import foo.bar.baz

...

foo.bar.baz.initialize()  # a lot of typing/clutter
```

```
from foo.bar.baz import initialize

...

initialize()  # risk of insidious shadowing bugs
```

```
import foo.bar.baz as fbb

...

fbb.initialize()  # safer, IMO
```

<sub>Granted, the last form does not completely eliminate the risk of shadowing bugs, in Python at least, module aliases can shadow each other (as well as unaliased module names) within a file; i.e. the following produces no warnings</sub>

```
import foo.bar.baz as fbb

...

import fro.bnitz.bong as fbb

...

fbb.initialize()
```

<sub>But this risk is mitigated by the Python convention of putting all import statements at the top of the file, which makes it easy to be aware of what aliases are already in use.</sub>

<sub>I don't know if OCaml supports such aliasing (or its "moral equivalent").  On the other hand, OCaml, unlike Python, my already have built-in safeguards against inadvertent shadowing of identifiers, which reduces the risk of working with the unqualified identifiers.</sub>

Comment: is this an `Core.Std` module that causes the problems?

Comment: In part yes: `open Core.Std` appears to be shadowed by a subsequent `open Foo` line, so I get an error saying that `String.strip` is unbound, which I was not getting before I added the `open Foo` line...

Comment: other modules can shadow names, they can't erase them. `String.strip` should became available as soon, as you `open Core.Std`.

Comment: @ivg: thanks; I found the places where I needed to replace `blah` with `Foo.blah`.  Thanks for alerting me not to try to get rid of `open Core.std`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, in OCaml we try not to open modules at all, and squeeze the scope of opened modules. For example, in OCaml you can open modules locally, with two different syntaxes:

```
 let sum x y = 
   let open Int64 in
   x + y
```

or, sometimes even more convenient:

```
 let sum x y = Int64.(x + y)
```

What concerning your question, I think that trial and error is a good choice. Especially if you're using good tools, like `emacs` and `merlin`. Otherwise, you can try to ask `utop` about the contents of the particular module:

```
 # #typeof "Int64";;
```

But beware, it can be very large.

P.S. I've updated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26812910/2625442) with information on how to use `utop`

### Update

I've forgot to note, that there're cases when you should open a module. Indeed, there is a tendency in a modern OCaml programming, to ship your libraries with one particular umbrella module, that will export all that you think you should export. It is something like python's packages. Also this helps to solve problems with namespace clashes, when you're linking.

So, if you're going to use `core` library, then you should start all your files with this `open Core.Std`.

By the way, if you have troubles with this module, then you should better try to read online documentation, instead of `#typeof`'ing it. It is too large. The official point of reference is [here](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/core/#Std), but there `css` sucks, so I would suggest you to use [this](http://ocaml-redesign.github.io/pkg/docs/?package=core&module=Std) reference, although it is outdated and unofficial.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than remove the open statement, you can get OCaml to protect you from shadowing bugs. If you turn on warning 44 (added in version 4.01), then OCaml will issue a warning whenever you use an identifier that was shadowed by an open statement. This warning can be silenced by using the `open!` syntax.

So in your example you should use:

```
open! Core.Std
open Foo
```

and compile it using warning 44:

```
ocamlc -w +44 bar.ml
```

This will give you a warning for each identifier you use from `Foo` that shadows something from `Core.Std`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a ready-made tool to do this tranformation, but that doesn't mean there isn't one. The compiler however does provide a key tool for this. Compile your program with the [`-annot` option](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/comp.html#s:comp-options). This produces a `.annot` file for each source file that contains information about various things inferred by the compiler, including types and bindings.

Here it is at work on a sample file.

```
open Str
let foo = regexp "foo"
let regexp x = 42
let shadow = regexp "foo"
```

Here are the parts of the `.annot` file corresponding to the two uses of the `regexp` identifier in expressions, the first being from the `Str` module and the second from the local redefinition.

```
"a.ml" 2 9 19 "a.ml" 2 9 25
type(
  string -> Str.regexp
)
ident(
  ext_ref Str.regexp
)
"a.ml" 4 50 63 "a.ml" 4 50 69
type(
  string -> int
)
ident(
  int_ref regexp "a.ml" 3 32 36 "a.ml" 3 32 42
)
```

The format of the `.annot` file isn't documented, but you can look at the source code and at various programs that parse it, including the Emacs mode shipped with OCaml. You may be able to reuse code from [OCamlSpotter](https://bitbucket.org/camlspotter/ocamlspot).

---

Regarding defining shortcuts for a module, the equivalent of Python's `import foo.bar.baz as fbb` is `module Fbb = Foo.Bar.Baz`. In OCaml up to version 4.01, the alias isn't equivalent for to the original in all contexts, because equality on abstract types is based on the module paths leading to the types, and OCaml only tracks type equalities, not module equalities. For example:

```
module S = String;;
fun (x : S.t) -> (x : String.t);;  (*fine: S.t is the same type as String.t*)
module StringSet = Set.Make(String);;
module SSet = Set.Make(S);;
fun (x : StringSet.elt) -> (x : SSet.elt);;  (*still fine, still the same type*)
fun (x : StringSet.t) -> (x : SSet.t);;  (*incompatible types*)
```

The abstract types `StringSet.t = Set.Make(String).t` and `SSet.t = Set.Make(S).t` are not compatible because OCaml doesn't see that `S` and `String` are the same module, it only goes as far as seeing that they happen to define the same types. Since OCaml 4.02, such aliases are tracked by the type checker and by the code generator, so I believe that `Fbb` and `Foo.Bar.Baz` can be used interchangeably.

Another difference with Python is that external modules don't need to be explicitly declared. OCaml's `open` is really Python's `import * from`; any external package can be used as a module without prior declaration.

Comment: Since version 4.02 OCaml tracks module aliases so `StringSet.t` and `SSet.t` will now be equivalent.